# Error seeding table data using EF Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am new to `MVC` and `EF Core` and have been trying to seed some data. All my tables seed correctly except for one table and I am tired of banging my head against a wall.  I have even recreated the entire application with no luck.  I am certain I am missing something obvious.

**My Models**

```
public class AgreementType
    {
        public int AgreementTypeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Creation Date")]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [DisplayName("Created By")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public Agreement Agreement { get; set; }
    }

public class ContactType
    {
        public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Creation Date")]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [DisplayName("Created By")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public Contact Contact { get; set; }
    }

public class Branch
    {
        public int BranchID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Creation Date")]
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [DisplayName("Created By")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public int IntermediaryID { get; set; }
        public Intermediary Intermediary { get; set; }

        public int RegionID { get; set; }
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
    }
```

**My Context Class**

```
public class BizDevHubContext : DbContext
    {
        public BizDevHubContext(DbContextOptions<BizDevHubContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<AgreementType> AgreementType { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Branch> Branch { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<AgreementType>().ToTable("AgreementType");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>().ToTable("Branch");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContactType>().ToTable("ContactType");

            // One to One            
            modelBuilder.Entity<Agreement>()
                .HasOne(b => b.AgreementType)
                .WithOne(i => i.Agreement)
                .HasForeignKey<Agreement>(b => b.AgreementTypeID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
                .HasOne(b => b.ContactType)
                .WithOne(i => i.Contact)
                .HasForeignKey<Contact>(b => b.ContactTypeID);

            //One to Many
            modelBuilder.Entity<Region>()
                .HasMany(c => c.Branch)
                .WithOne(e => e.Region)
                .HasForeignKey((p => p.BranchID));

            // Set default dates 
            modelBuilder.Entity<AgreementType>()
            .Property(b => b.CreationDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Branch>()
            .Property(b => b.CreationDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");

            modelBuilder.Entity<ContactType>()
            .Property(b => b.CreationDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
        }
    }
```

**My Initializer Class**

```
    if (context.Branch.Any())
                {
                    return;
                }

                var branches = new Branch[]
                {
                 new Branch{Name="Bloemfontein",CreationDate=DateTime.Now,CreatedBy="System"},
                 new Branch{Name="Cape Town",CreationDate=DateTime.Now,CreatedBy="System"},
                 new Branch{Name="Durban",CreationDate=DateTime.Now,CreatedBy="System"},
                 new Branch{Name="Nelspruit",CreationDate=DateTime.Now,CreatedBy="System"},
                 new Branch{Name="Johannesburg",CreationDate=DateTime.Now,CreatedBy="System"},
                 new Branch{Name="Port Shepstone",CreationDate=DateTime.Now,CreatedBy="System"},
                 new Branch{Name="Pretoria",CreationDate=DateTime.Now,CreatedBy="System"}
                };
                foreach (Branch b in branches)
                {
                    context.Branch.Add(b);

                }
                context.SaveChanges();
```

The other tables all seed except the Branch table.

Please help!

Comment: Do you receive any error? See in the visual studio output window also.
And where are you calling your  Initializer Class

Comment: @Jason Ebersey, Where is the error message that you are receiving?

Comment: @MuhammadKamranAslam I receive this error in the output 
The property 'BranchID' on entity type 'Branch' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

Comment: have you defined BranchId as an IdentityColumn, configure it as DatabaseGenerated in the config